# Is it possible to use a javascript bookmarklet to invoke a locally stored/locally hosted Java applet?

Tags: java, javascript, web-services, web-applications, browser

Wondering if this is possible, I have a java applet which I am embedding on my own version of website login pages (using wordpress currently) and using a Java applet to allow for login with a smartcard token which has the login details stored on it.

I was wondering if it was possible to use a javascript bookmarklet or something similar to load this Java Applet and add this functionality to pages which I do not have control of?

Thanks.

Edit: Currently I use the following code on pages which I can edit the html/php on, but I'd like to add it to other sites where I cannot do this with a javascript bookmarklet if possible. Pass happens to be the name of the function run by the page when the submit button is pressed.

```
  <script language="JavaScript"><!--
  function pass()
  {
    document.tstapp.put();
    document.loginform.user_login.value = document.tstapp.get();
    document.loginform.user_pass.value = document.tstapp.get2();

  }
  //-->
  </script>

  <APPLET name=tstapp code=LoginCard21.class archive="Cardv2.jar"  WIDTH=100 HEIGHT=30>
  </APPLET>
```

Comment: It's probably possible. Could you give us your normal code for appending the applet so we can test it?

Comment: <script language="JavaScript"><!--
      function pass()
      {
        document.tstapp.put();
        document.loginform.user_login.value = document.tstapp.get();
     document.loginform.user_pass.value = document.tstapp.get2();
    
      }
      //-->
      </script>
    
      <APPLET name=tstapp code=LoginCard21.class archive="Cardv2.jar"  WIDTH=100 HEIGHT=30>
      </APPLET>

Comment: Wow the formatting really got messed up. Hah. I'll edit into the main question too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
javascript:var applet = document.createElement('applet'); applet.name = 'tstapp'; applet.code = 'LoginCard21.class'; applet.archive = 'Cardv2.jar'; applet.width = 100; applet.height = 30; document.body.appendChild(applet); var pass = function () { document.tstapp.put(); document.loginform.user_login.value = document.tstapp.get(); document.loginform.user_pass.value = document.tstapp.get2(); };
```

The crux of this bookmarklet; that I think you didn't know about, is [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createElement).

Comment: That looks like exactly what I was hoping existed! Thanks very much!